# How to secure a ext.js-app with keycloak?

Tags: javascript, extjs, keycloak, sencha-architect

I want to secure a simple ext.js-App (the QuickStart-App) with Sencha Architect but I am unsure where to put all the keycloak-related stuff.

Do I have to put it in app.json? Directly in index.html?

Thanks!